# what causing an error about 'lc-messages-dir' when i initialize mysql-5.7.17

Tags: mysql

```
[root@wwwlxg bin]# ./mysqld --initialize --user=mysql --basedir=/opt/mysql/mysql --datadir=/opt/mysql/mysql/data
[Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
[Warning] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
[Warning] 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER' sql mode was not set.

[ERROR] Can't find error-message file '/opt/mysql/mysql/data/errmsg.sys'. Check error-message file location and 'lc-messages-dir' configuration directive.
[Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
[Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
[Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 73963455-d30a-11e6-bf4f-3aa0c659e827.
[Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
[Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: t&VhwEgod4rm
```

---

hereis my.cnf

```
# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
 basedir = /opt/mysql/
datadir = /opt/mysql/data
 port = 3306
server_id = 1
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
lc_messages_dir = /opt/mysql/data
language = /opt/mysql/share/english
```

> there is an error about  'lc-messages-dir'  i want to know what's that and how i can fix it?(this question was solved) because i add this to my.cnf :lc_messages_dir = /opt/mysql/data

---

another error when i mysql.server start

```
ps -ef|grep mysql
no other mysql is running 
ls -l /opt/mysql
im sure /opt/mysql is  mysql:mysql
```

---

```
Starting MySQL... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/opt/mysql/data/wwwlxg.pid).
```

---

> im running: centos6.4  mysql-5.7.17-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64

Comment: This question looks like it's better placed on our sister site [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Reformatted question and adjusted the language.  I also agree with the placement being better suited for server fault.

Comment: thank you very much, ill adjust it :)

Answer (score 4):

try

my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
...
lc_messages_dir = /opt/mysql/share
lc_messages = en_US
```

errmsg.sys usually in /{mysql-path}/mysql/share/{language}/, {language} would be 'english', 'spanish' ...

for more detail: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-message-language.html

Answer (score 1):

Generally when you install MySQL, a directory for lc_messages configuration is created in the system, normally in /usr/share/mysql-.

The correct configuration in **my.cnf** for this is the following (in my case MySQL 8.0):

```
[mysqld]
lc-messages-dir                         = /usr/share/mysql-8.0
lc-messages                             = en_US
```

If you specify directly the language in the lc-message-dir such as /usr/share/mysql-8.0/english where the **errmsg.sys** is, then you will receive the following warning:

> Using pre 5.5 semantics to load error messages from
>   /usr/share/mysql-8.0/english/. If this is not intended, refer to the
>   documentation for valid usage of --lc-messages-dir and --language
>   parameters.

The key is using the **lc-messages-dir** and **lc-messages** correctly.

Answer (score 1):

you must make the --defaults-file=# **as first parameter** in one line, like this :

```
./bin/mysqld  --defaults-file=my57.cnf --initialize
```

see more :https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization.html

hope helpful to you  :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the path of the file `errmsg.sys` does not exist.
Check if the folder `/opt/mysql/mysql/data` exists and if not, create it.
Maybe you also have to adjust the permissions of this folder by using `chown mysql:mysql /opt/mysql/mysql/data`.

Comment: i did what you told me ,and add a line in my.cnf now this problem is gone     i add this line  lc_messages_dir = /opt/mysql/data
language = /opt/mysql/share/english

Comment: but another problem comes :Starting MySQL... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/opt/mysql/data/wwwlxg.pid).i cant find wwwlxg.pid in my data.     i tried to find if other mysql isntance is runiing ,but there is not .and /opt/mysql  is mysql:mysql

Comment: @Keven.Lee, Btw did you create the errmsg.sys file yourself or did you let mysql create it itself?